# How can I save a custom type as binary data in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, byte, save

I'm creating something that has save files.  For the most part, it's just saving objects with 4 values.

- x
- y
- id
- layer

I've been saving this as XML for a while, the problem is, the files are starting to get HUGE because I'm saving hundreds to thousands of these objects and XML is kind of bulky for something like this.  I tried switching to Json but it was too big as well (I will admit though, better).

**My Question**

I know a lot of programs save directly using bytes to conserve space.  I want to do this.  Say I have 300 objects with the properties X, Y, Id, and Layer, how could I save this to file x as bytes and load it later?

I've tried reading bytes when I used to make my own servers.  I usually ended up getting frustrated and giving up.  I'm hoping this isn't too similar (my gut says otherwise).

**EDIT**

Oh sorry guys, I forgot to mention, I'm using `VB.NET` so all `.NET` answers are acceptable!  :)

Also, all of these values are integers.

Comment: Saving to bytes is a Binary Serialization. BTW, Which development language are you using?

Comment: How are you saving objects to XML? Are you using XmlSerializer class?

Comment: @sll I was just saving them manually, I can't serialize it because it's data I'm hand picking from multiple arrays.

Comment: @sll I guess I could serialize the individual elements....

Comment: so you do not have a class which represents/encapsulates an item to be serialized?

Comment: @sll I do now, I hadn't though about doing it that way.  The actual class contains tons of data, most of it is only needed/generated while the program is running.  I only needed the id, layer, x, and y.  I've made a class now that strips it down to just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use protobuf-net (I would; I'm biased...). It is an open-source .NET serializer, that uses attributes (well, that is optional in v2) to guide it. For example, using C# syntax (purely for my convenience - the engine doesn't care what language you use):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Whatever {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int X {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Y {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public long Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public string Layer {get;set;}
}
```

You can then serialize, for example:

```
List<Whatever> data = ...
Serializer.Serialize(file, data);
```

and deserialize:

```
var data = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Whatever>>(file);
```

job done; fast binary output. You probably *can* get a *little* tighter by hand-coding all reading/writing manually without any markers etc, but the above will be a lot less maintenane. It'll also be easy to load into any other platform that has a "protocol buffers" implementation available (which is: most of them).

Comment: Looks promising, I'm trying it out now.

Comment: I just got an error, I'm not sure what to do next:  `Duplicate field-number detected; 1 on: RedSim.RedSimEngine.Whatever`

Comment: @Dade what numbers are you using? Note mine are *unique* within the class (1,2,3,4) - note also that they must be positive integers (0, -1, etc are all illegal)

Comment: Oh, my bad, you must have changed it after I tried it.  Lol.  Thanks, I'll try that now.

Comment: Very much so!  Everything is running smoothly and I feel great!

Comment: Just of interest to compare size of XML and protobuf-serialized output?

Comment: @Dade see sll's comment - are you able to volunteer any data here?

Comment: @sll, sorry for the wait.  I actually deleted all the old saves and emptied the trash can.  If I remember correctly (these were small sample tests) the XML file was over 4 times larger then the proto-buf version.

Comment: @sll see above, courtesy of Dade

Comment: @Dade: thanks, interesting to know! I've also used protobuf-net but have compared it vs ZeroC Ice serialization results. protobuf-net won this challenge as well

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:
why not xml and zip (or some other compression)

Advantage: 
* its still "human" readable 
* text files have normaly a good compression factor

Also what programming languae you are using?
in C/C++ or you create a struct with the data 
reinterpret cast the struct to byte * and write sizeof bytes to the file... simple as that
(assuming the struct is fixed size (id and layer are also fixed sized variables like int)

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t  you use a database like MySql or SQL ?

Comment: I'll not use this for the same reason something like word, excel, or most other programs don't use a database to save files.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood you. I thought you only needed to store 4 variables but did not get that you needed to store them in files. Thought it was only the info you were storing. My bad.